# NLP - Extract the action verb, noun from a list of instructions

Tags: nlp

I am looking for some directions on how to perform my ideas.
I will have a recipe with the ingredients' name, equipment list and the cooking method. What I want to do is simplifed the cooking method into just the action verb, ingredients' name and equipment's name.

- For example:

  1. Ingredient: Eggs , pepper , salt
  2. Equipment: Jug
  3. Method: 1. Crack the eggs into a jug.

     2. Add pepper and salt

The output will be store in a list.
Output: 1. Crack , eggs , jug
        2. Add, pepper, jug
        3. Add, salt , jug

Answer (score 0):

With NLP you can have your whole text tagged with parts of speech. After tagging your whole text, you know that `ingredients` and `equipments` are always **nouns**, and "action verbs" are **verbs**. Now you can break your problem in three parts

1. How can you make a distinction between equipments and ingredients.
2. Detect which verbs are "action verbs" and related to your problem Domain,  such as "add, mix, cut .."
3. Create sentence patterns. [Action verb] [ingredient] [equipment]

In **1** you could take all nouns, and use `word frequency` to create a "bag of equipments and ingredients words". The rationale behind this technique is that, these words are more likely to be used frequently as they are part of the problem domain.Then to distinguish between each other you could use data mining, **affinity analysis** for example.

In **2** you could parse a bunch of recipes, extract all verbs and get the most frequent ones. Create a "bag of verbs" and use stemming to put them in their infinitive or base form. For example "cutting" and "cutted" should be the same as "cut". With this seed (your bag of verbs), u can use regex after to scan these verbs in your recipes.

In **3** you'll need to find a sentence pattern. Maybe you will find more than one

This is a good starting point and should give you some ideas. Combine NLP and data mining/machine learning to get more insight about your data